# Why do Image transformations rename the image?

Tags: image-transforms, seo

I noticed that when performing an image transition on an image, the resulting image name is computer gibberish. How can I maintain the original name of the image? Keeping the original name is important for SEO value.

**EDIT**
When viewing a transformed image for first time, the url shows as  http://aed.dev/cpresources/transforms/3?x=pEYIdgIMS ... but! I have discovered that this url only appears the first time I view the page. every other page view will display the image with original file name

Comment: Can you give an example of the names you are seeing? Are you using any image related plugins?

Comment: here is an example - http://aed.dev/cpresources/transforms/3?x=pEYIdgIMS ... but! I have discovered that this url only appears the first time I view the page. every other page view will display the image with original file name

Comment: Ahh, that's correct.  The first time an untransformed image is request, it'll get that URL, but subsequent requests end up serving the transformed image as a static asset directly.  If you'd like to add that as an official answer, I'll upvote it. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Craft will use the original file name of the asset after the first request.

The first time an asset is requested, the url for the asset will not include the original file name